# The Search API module shows a two-words taxonomy term as two separated words, in its widget

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I am using taxonomy terms to classify my content, and the Search API and Facets modules for searching.

I have some nodes that are tagged with "Asian Cuisine" term; after indexing the content, "Asian Cuisine" is handled as two separated words.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid it happens?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your search index field settings? I've honestly never seen that happen, and I used Search API quite a bit.

Comment: thanks @KyleTaylored . here are the links .

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbq0egjbsk5gaaf/pic1.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxm3lfhvyfyyh2f/pic2.jpg

Comment: Did you apply the "tokenizer" filter to the field?

Comment: @arrubiu, thanks for the tip. I turned it on at my taxonomy field and it worked. but also i changed the setting of my Taxonomy field to "String" instead of "FullText". So some of it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, consider using the "Taxonomy Term" type for the field indexes. This should remedy your issue.

By using Full Text, you're breaking up the taxonomy term names into searchable words. Use either the default taxonomy term value, or try using the "All Parent Terms" field.

[image: Normal taxonomy term field index.]

Comment: thanks @KyleTaylored. but does this has to do any thing with the below screen .

https://www.dropbox.com/s/87npj9k7y558ndy/test_recep%20%20%20Site%20Install_.png

Can't i just use one search box to search any thing ?

Comment: For both the facets and fulltext search work, you need to index the fields separately. The Facets will work properly when using the Taxonomy Term type, and then you can index the Term Names using the Fulltext type that should then should show up when using the search box.

Comment: @KyleTaylored, I'm having the same issue but I'm using the address field. So I can not change it to a Taxonomy Term. What should I do in this case ?

Comment: What can be done when the facet field is a text field ?